# How to answer by clicking in R

Tags: r

I would try to make the small game as [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkNV0rSndJ0). I would try to substitute clicking for touch screen. It is easy on the exterior, however I cannot find any solution for this problem.

I was wondering if you could help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, but `?identify` will let you read mouse clicks from the user.

Comment: Or look into the canvas widget in the `tcltk` package.

Comment: This is a good question, with a very nice answer. I don't understand why it was closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.seed(123)
y <- runif(9)
x <- runif(9)

# 1. Numbers 1-9 appear on the screen for some time
plot(x, y, pch = as.character(1:9), 
     xlab = "", ylab = "",  
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
     xlim = c(-0.05, 1.05), ylim = c(-0.05, 1.05))
Sys.sleep(3)

# 2. Black boxes replace numbers and now one is allowed to click on them
for(i in 1:9) {
  plot(x[i:9], y[i:9], pch = 15, cex = 3,
       xlab = "", ylab = "",  
       xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
       xlim = c(-0.05, 1.05), ylim = c(-0.05, 1.05))
  ans <- identify(x, y, n = 1, plot = FALSE)
  if(ans != i){
    cat("Game over")
    break
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The answer is "identify".